# Advices on how to structure a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to add tables in my database in order to stock information like this :

```
user 1
2015:
- 3 times at bowling
- 10 times at cinema
2014:
- 2 times at bowling
- 3 times at the restaurant 
- 5 times at cinema
user 2
2015:
- 1 time at the restaurant
- 3 times at the cinema
2014:
- 2 times at bowling
2013:
- 3 times at the restaurant
- 1 time at bowling

user 1
2015:
- 1 time doctor
- 1 time dentist
2014:
- 2 times doctor
user 2
2015:
- 2 times doctor
- 1 time ophthalmologist
```

The number of years differ according to the users, the number of hobbies, doctor and so on.
There is also global data on the user which differ from one year to another (for instance the number of vaacation days).

I thought to this structure :

```
Global table :
userId - year - nbHolidays -

Hobbies table :
userId - year - activityId - numberOfTimes

medical table :
userId - year - kindDoctorId - numberOfTimes
```

I have not a lot of experience with database conception, do you think this is a good structure ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization Read about normalization. This is also not a SO Question.

Comment: I think you can Distribute the data among three tables. Users -> this table have user id and user name.   year -> have year id, Year   and your data table with have user id, year id, and activity, number of times.

Comment: You are better off storing each instance of when a user did an activity (i.e. store the User, the Activity, and the Time). Then you will be able to flexibly query to get the data you need - so if in the future you need to break it down by month, instead of year, you will be able to. Always consider what data you might want to extract *in the future*...

Comment: Thank you for your remarks.